# Portable way to use a local shared read/write storage (file/database) as a cache for multiple python scripts/processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, portability, shared

I am looking for a module or a library to be able to read and write values in a way as a simple python dictionary does it with simple values (numbers/strings/lists/subdictionaries).

Without insane set of methods or classes without a clear example like here:
https://dogpilecache.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core_usage.html#example-using-dogpile-directly-for-caching

Currently I've found that the `fcache` would be pretty simple to go: https://fcache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

But initial tests with multiple script access shows exceptions on access:

**test1.py**

```
from fcache.cache import FileCache

mycache = FileCache('1')

while True:
  mycache['test'] = '111'
  mycache.sync()
  x = mycache['test']
  if x != '111' and x != '222':
    print('=', x)
```

**test2.py**

```
from fcache.cache import FileCache

mycache = FileCache('1')

while True:
  mycache['test'] = '222'
  mycache.sync()
  x = mycache['test']
  if x != '111' and x != '222':
    print('=', x)
```

**test1.py** output:

```
Error opening file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\1\1\Cache\cache\74657374
= None
```

**test2.py** output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    mycache.sync()
  File "C:\Python\x86\38\lib\site-packages\fcache\cache.py", line 183, in sync
    self._write_to_file(filename, self._buffer[ekey])
  File "C:\Python\x86\38\lib\site-packages\fcache\cache.py", line 250, in _write_to_file
    os.chmod(filename, self._mode)
OSError: [WinError 6800] The function attempted to use a name that is reserved for use by another transaction: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\1\\1\\Cache\\cache\\7465737
4'
```

The `multiprocessing.Lock` could not help to fix that, as the same errors depends on something else additionally to an exclusive access.

Seems the `fcache` is not compatible with the multiprocess access.

I want to store a set of values as in a shared table, where a flag would indicated a row actuality. And if a flag is or not is raised, then a row has to be removed from the table.

I don't have insane quantity of process, I don't have insane quantity of python objects with different nature to store. Only simple values, maybe hundred, not more.

Is there already existed, simple, reliable and sane way to access one simple file or files without a huge pile of lines of code for multiple scripts/processes?

Answer (score 0):

I know may be this solution is a dork, but at least it plain simple and pass the test on Windows:

**test1.py** (tested in python 3.8 on Windows and Linux Mint)

```
from fcache.cache import FileCache
import time

mycache = FileCache('1')

i = 0
count = 0
y = '111'

while True:
  try:
    mycache['test'] = y
    mycache.sync()
    x = mycache['test']
    if x is None:
      print('FAILED', count, x)
    else:
      print('SUCCEED', count, x)
      i = 0
  except:
    # retry, has meaning on Windows
    i += 1
    if i % 10 == 0:
      # give to scheduler a break
      time.sleep(.02)
    continue
  count += 1

  if count % 10 == 0:
    # give to scheduler a break
    time.sleep(.02)
```

**test2.py**

```
<<<The same code as above>>>
```

And has worked out on my machine around 10 scripts in parallel.